# selecting which columns are displayed in the kendo angular grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

is there a standardized interface that comes with the grid for the user to select which columns to display?
or is it an upcoming feature  in the September release?

Answer (score 1):

The visibility of the columns can be configured via the kendo-grid-column's `hidden` property:

[COLUMN FEATURES --> HIDDEN STATE](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/#toc-hidden-state)

```
<kendo-grid-column
              field="..."
              [hidden]="true"
            >...
```

Comment: I know this, I was wondering if there is a standardized way like in the jquery version, or if one is being developed for the version later on this month?

Comment: If you mean the column menu feature of the jQuery Grid, such a functionality is not currently available, but will be considered for the January release, based on the customer demand in the UserVoice portal:

[http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-feedback/suggestions/17785177-add-grid-column-menu-like-it-s-implemented-in-jque](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-feedback/suggestions/17785177-add-grid-column-menu-like-it-s-implemented-in-jque)